# Why in Combinatorics, can't we obtain formula for unordered not-unique choice from ordered not-unique choice by dividing by factorial?

Tags: combinatorics

We have formula for ordered unique choice: $N^m$, where N is number of elements in set and m is number of 'seats' we want to fill.
There is formula for unordered unique choice: binomial coefficient $N \choose m$.

But why instead of binomial coefficient can't we simply divide the first formula by factorial of m; isn't that what factorial should do? The formula would be: $\frac{N^m}{m!}$

EDIT: 
It seems I did mess the formulas l little (a lot). Sorry for that.
So we have $\frac{N!}{(N-m)!}$ and we can divide it by $m!$ to obtain $N \choose m$. So we have ordered distinct and then unordered distinct choices. So how do I apply this reasoning to $N^m$, that is go from ordered not-distinct to not-ordered not-distinct? (@JMoravitz could you elaborate some more on why $m!$ won't work? Can I divide by something else to make it work?)

Comment: Note that your proposed formula isn't even an integer in many cases.  For example, if $N$ is odd and $m>1$

Comment: The problem is that the "reduction factor" you seek for sequences with (possible) repeats is not uniform; e.g. with $m=3$, the unordered triple [$a,a,a$] corresponds to only $1$ ordered triple, while [$a,a,b$] corresponds to $3$ and [$a,b,c$] to $6$. So dividing by $3! = 6$ won't work, and there's no simple factor to divide into $N^3$ to get the number of distinct multisets. In this example, the number of unordered triples equals the number of ways to write $3$ as a sum of $N$ non-neg. integers which equals $C(N+2,3)$ by the technique called "stars and bars."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for $N^m$ versus $\binom{N}{m}$... they count very different things... $N^m$ you have "$m$ balls" and "$N$ bins", each of which distinct, and we want to find how many ways we can put the balls in the bins, where we allow more than one ball per bin and balls are distinct.  $\binom{N}{m}$ would count the number of ways of putting those $m$ balls into the $N$ bins were we to ignore the uniqueness of the balls with the additional constraint that we may never put more than one ball in each bin.

---

Now... it can make sense to divide by a value to correct a count.  This can be described by analogy as the "Shepherd's Principle."

Imagine a shepherd in a field with a flock of sheep.  The shepherd wants to count how many sheep there are, but the bodies of the sheep are all white and fluffy and difficult to distinguish.  He can however squat down and clearly see each of the legs of the sheep and can count those.  Knowing that each sheep has exactly four legs, rather than counting the sheep directly by their bodies he can instead count the total number of legs and divide the count by four.

That is to say, if we want to count the number of objects/arrangements there are, and given an approach to counting we arrive at a total of $T$ but we know that every outcome was overcounted having been counted exactly $k$ times each in this attempt, we may get the correct total by dividing giving $\frac{T}{k}$.

---

In your case, you are proposing to divide by $m!$ to "correct the count" in order to have "ignored" the uniqueness of the balls.  This doesn't work however as the various final outcomes that you are interested in are not counted $m!$ times each.

Answer (score 0):

But that **is** what the factorial does! You just started with the wrong number. The number of ways to choose an ordered sequence of $m$ distinct elements is $$N(N-1)\cdots(N-m+1) = \frac{N!}{(N-m)!}$$ while the number of $m$-element subsets is obtained by forgetting the order, that is dividing the above by $m!$: $$\frac{N!}{(N-m)!m!}={N\choose m}$$ and everything agrees.